# WooCommerce modify text "This product is currently out of stock and unavailable"

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using WordPress/WooCommerce with the plugin Booster.
I'm trying to hide the prices and "Add to Cart" button for visitors from China.  Using Booster, I was able to do this, but instead of displaying prices and "Add to Cart", it is displaying "This product is out of stock and unavailable".

How can I change the text to something more useful, such as "Please contact us for more information on this product"?

Thanks for any help!
Rick

Answer (score -1):

If you want to remove prices and add to cart button from shop page to all your products, try this hook

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', , 'your_func_name', 10 );
add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'your_function_name', 10 );

function your_function_name()
{
remove_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item','woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10 );
}
function your_func_name()
{
remove_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title','woocommerce_template_loop_price', 10 );
?>
   <div>
    <?php _e('This product is out of stock and unavailable'); ?>
    <p><?php _e('Please contact us for more information on this product'); ?>                             </p>
</div>
<?php
}
```